# Does RSA use two one-way functions?

Tags: cryptography

I'm trying to understand the concepts behind RSA right now. From what I've learned so far, it's pretty much all about a one-way function with a trapdoor: Raising the message to the e'th power modulo N, where the factorization of N is kind of the trapdoor.

But on the other hand, I've got the one-way function where I multiply two big primes to receive N. So can one talk about two different one-way functions where the first is used to receive the trapdoor of the other?

Comment: These might be of help: goo.gl/eFmmg2 and goo.gl/FvU9EP .

Comment: Thanks, but I already mostly know how RSA works; I'm just not sure if it's the right way to express it as that the first one-way function generates the trapdoor of the second one. I mean, it kind of is true if I look at your links, but I'm not sure if you can express it like that. Most texts about RSA always talk about just one one-way function, that's pretty much what confuses me.

Comment: For what it's worth, I found, to my amazement, that, for a given prime product $PQ$ (as used in the cited articles), it is possible to develop the exponents $E$ and $D$ so that they are equal. The result is that the same exponent can be used for both encryption and decryption.